# Storing files on a datastore and getting back their location to store for later retrieval

Tags: node.js, mongodb, file, photo, ubuntu-16.04

I will need to store photo's on a datastore, store the location in Mongo so I can retrieve it later to display. What is a good way to go about doing this? If I just google I end up getting information on accessing the files in node itself.....

At this point I am not sure what datastore I will use, for now just on another server I have, Ubuntu Server.

Answer (score 0):

I made something like what you need. I had to store photos on s3 and store the path on mongo. If you use amanzon too, they provide a sdk, that contains all possible functions for interactions with the cloud. So you'll need a way to work with asynchronous tasks when store the data in the cloud, I used async module to manage the functions. I hope I gave you some direction where go to. I can't help you code, once I don't know your business rules, good lucky